# Convert to json string in Android

Tags: android, json

I am Having Contact class  With firstname, lastname, phoneno, and Email properties.

- i want to pass `ArrayList<Contact>` to Web page (load url) as a json string.

How to do this... 
my Code:

```
 function Callback(result)
{
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert information of a class into a JSON string? No problem- [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) will help you out.

In your case, you would have to do something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

ArrayList<Contact> contact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
//add some contacts
....

for(Contact c : contact) {
     sb.append(gson.toJson(c));
}

String strToPass = sb.toString();
```

Comment: without GSON is there any other option?

Comment: yeah you can do this manually, which is tedious, especially when your class gets complicated. gson is pretty useful- its very simple, its pretty lightweight, and its developed by google. you can't go wrong.

Comment: i download the jar file from GSON. i don't know how to include into my project???...

Comment: right click your project, click properties, click java build path, go to the libraries tab, and from here you should be able to locate your gson jar file.

Comment: {"EmailAddress":"c0@gmail.com","FirstName":"a0","LastName":"b0","PhoneNumber":"90098789780"}{"EmailAddress":"c1@gmail.com","FirstName":"a1","LastName":"b1","PhoneNumber":"90098789781"}getting like this, how can i eval in html page using jscript, because i need to access obj.FirstName like this

Comment: that is an entirely different question (plus it is an unclear question bec i dont fully get what you mean). but from what i understand, i think that depends on how the server is implemented to handle the incoming json data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Json Simple Library](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), you can easily map between JSON and Java Entities, in you case it can directly convert your Array List to a JSON Array ...

Example :

```
  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
  list.add("foo");
  list.add(new Integer(100));
  list.add(new Double(1000.21));
  list.add(new Boolean(true));
  list.add(null);
  String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```